# Python Class Duplication

Tags: python

Is it bad practice to use the same names for classes inside tools that both get executed into the same python environment, simultaneously?

I've created two python widgets as seen in the image below. Each of the widgets contain QTreeViews that use their own custom SortModel.

[image]

I was wondering if it's bad practice to name both of the **SortModel** and  **MainWindow** classes the same between the two files?

Because i later load both files into the same tool as Tabs. I'm starting to get some weird bugs in the program and I have a feeling this may be causing it.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542). *“I'm starting to get some weird bugs in the program and I have a feeling this may be causing it.”* – Maybe you should start with describing those bugs and your overall environment. Then you can mention that you believe it could be caused by those classes with the same name.

Comment: It shoulnd't be a problem if you namespace them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have to *import* both classes into the same module namespace, using the same name for distinct classes is more of a bad idea than a bad practice.

The current module will use only one of the classes for all cases where you need one of both; weird results.

However, you can distinguish one from the other at the import level by using the `import as` feature:

```
from camera_publish import SortModel as CameraSortModel
from cache_publish import SortModel as CacheSortModel
```

Comment: does this also apply the actual Widgets themselves im assuming to

Comment: Yes, it does. Remember to do the appropriate renames in your module for each of the classes

Comment: @M ok thank you. I'll make sure to do that. I appreciate the help with this.
While you are here, each of my Original Widgets, have closeEvents that normally would get executed when running each Widget individually. Is there a way to emit that same signal when they are placed inside a tab widget and that tab widget closes?

Comment: The `import ... as` syntax will not change the behavior of your classes, the names are only masked by the new ones

Comment: I'll make sure to change the names in the original code files.